# Reading hibernate annotations attribute value from properties file

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Test")
public class Test {

@Column(name="EXRA_INFO",length=200)
    private String extraInfo;
*******
}
```

here we are specifying the column attributes value in java file only. Is there anyway to read these attributes value from properties file and make it configurable, so that in future if I need to change length value, it will be changed in proerties file only. Please help!!

Comment: not a good design, for how many entities you should keep.

Comment: Not for too many. But I just want to know that whether we can do it. Please let me know if there is a way

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't keep it in property file because annotation attributes must be a compile time constant.

However, you can put it in a Java class as constants. This way you change only that class when configuration needs to be changed. Something like this:

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
    public static final String TEST_TABLE_NAME = "Test";
    public static final String TEST_EXTRA_INFO = "EXTRA_INFO";
    public static final int STRING_COLUMN_LENGTH = 200;
}
```

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Config.TEST_TABLE_NAME)
public class Test {

@Column(name = Config.TEST_EXTRA_INFO, length = Config.STRING_COLUMN_LENGTH)
    private String extraInfo;
}
```